# Image change when hover for play and stop button in as3 at cs5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i am new to action script and flash,i am creating online radio player. Here i am faced simple problem. i want to change the button image whether it's play or stop button when i hover the image. i was create symbol for each button and created instance name. and i am put the first play button and next play-over button and stop button and stopover button respectively. i was done this all in one layer. here my hover action script

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;
import flash.events.Event;

/****stop-control:***/

btnstop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,StopOut);
btnstopo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,StopOver);
function StopOver(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    btnstopo.visible=false;
    btnstop.visible=true;
}

function StopOut(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    btnstop.visible=false;
    btnstopo.visible=true;
}

/*****Play control:****/

playbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,PlayOut);
btnplayo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,PlayOver);

function PlayOver(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    btnplayo.visible=false;
    playbtn.visible=true;
}

function PlayOut(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    playbtn.visible=false;
    btnplayo.visible=true;
} 

var soundfile:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://live32.radio.com:80/;stream1.mp3');
var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();

 var isplay=1;
 var myMusic:Sound = new Sound();  
 myMusic.load(soundfile);
 channel=myMusic.play(); 

playbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,PlayRadio);
btnstop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,StopRadio);

function PlayRadio(evt:Event):void
{
    if(isplay==0)
    {
        isplay=1;
        /*var myMusic:Sound = new Sound();  
        myMusic.load(soundfile);
        channel=myMusic.play(); */
        SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);
        btnstop.visible=true;
        playbtn.visible=false;
    }
}

function StopRadio(evt:Event):void
{
    if(isplay==1)
    {
        SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
        isplay=0;
        btnstop.visible=false;
        playbtn.visible=true;
    }
}
```

here my problem is when i am hit the stop button it's working fine. but after stop i need to show the play button. but as per my code it's show the stop button again after stop. i know the reason why it's show stop button. The MOUSE_OUT is the reason for that. i dont know how can i fix that. please clear anyone, thanks advance

Answer (score 0):

i found answer myself. i was missed `removeEventlistner` when i click the stop or play button.
here if i click stop button remove the stop EventLIstner and Add the Play EventLIstner. like opposite for play button the sample code here

```
function PlayRadio(evt:Event):void
{
    if(isplay==0)
    {
        isplay=1;
        /*var myMusic:Sound = new Sound();  
        myMusic.load(soundfile);
        channel=myMusic.play(); */
        btnplay.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,PlayOut);
        btnplayo.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,PlayOver);
        btnstop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,StopOut);
        btnstopo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,StopOver);
        SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);
        btnstop.visible=true;
        btnplay.visible=false;
    }
}

function StopRadio(evt:Event):void
{
    if(isplay==1)
    {
        btnstop.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,StopOut);
        btnstopo.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,StopOver);
        btnplay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,PlayOut);
        btnplayo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,PlayOver);
        SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
        isplay=0;
        btnstop.visible=false;
        btnplay.visible=true;
    }
```